# How to move a rectangle to the position of another rectangle, of different size, with tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm quite new to **Python**, and coding in general, and recently I started a simple (or not-so-simple) project of making a revamped version of the classic *Space Invaders* using **tk** in the form of **tkinter**. I came upon a problem, though, which I had no idea how to fix: how to move a rectangle(the bullet) to another rectangle(the spaceship). I created the bullet by creating them at 0, 0 , but then I don't know how to move them exactly to the spaceship. Thanks!

There's probably an easy solution that I haven't stumbled upon.

Answer (score 1):

When you create something on the canvas initially (such as the rectangle), you can store the item id by saving the result to a variable, like

```
square = canv.create_rectangle(bbox, **options)
```

Later, you can use move, itemconfig, or itemconfigure to move the object someplace else, like

```
canv.move(square, dx, dy)
```

where dx and dy are the offsets from current position.

Alternatively, if you want to make an object out of multiple shapes, you can assign tags to them and manipulate the object all at once by tags, as follows:

```
canv.create_rectangle(bbox, tags=('square'))
canv.move('square', dx, dy)
```

Two resources I found very useful were 
http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html 
and
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the answer I was looking for. In reality, before I had even written that question I knew of the `move` function, but it just wouldn't do! Then, a while ago, I thought of an answer. Thanks for helping, though!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're drawing the rectangle on a canvas, you can use the [move](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.move-method) method of the canvas to move an item from its current position to a new position.